# Swiftにて予測変換候補を取得する方法

Tags: swift, xcode

iPhoneで文字を入力していて、キーボードの上に表示される予測変換候補を取得する方法がわからず、悩んでおります。
ご存知の方がいれば、ご教授願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOSのAPIに日本語変換システムとやりとりできるようなものはありません。
ですので変換候補をプログラムから取得することはできません。

Comment: そうなんですね。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/homeskill/20100929/1285764728
こういうやり方をしている方がいらっしゃったので、出来るものと思ってしまいました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご提示の記事に書かれている方法はプライベートAPIを使った方法ですね。非公開のAPIを無理やり利用する、という方法なら実現の可能性はなくはないです。